# Passar uma lista para outra pagina - javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-eventos

Estou querendo passar uma lista que são adicionadas em uma pagina e clicando no botão de remover essa lista(linha) ir para outra pagina(final.html).

```js
function adicionaLinha(idTabela) {
  var tabela = document.getElementById(idTabela);
  var numeroLinhas = tabela.rows.length;
  var linha = tabela.insertRow(numeroLinhas);
  var celula1 = linha.insertCell(0);
  var celula2 = linha.insertCell(1);   
  var celula3 = linha.insertCell(2); 
  celula1.innerHTML = 'Quarto '+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
  celula2.innerHTML =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
  celula3.innerHTML =  "<button onclick='removeLinha(this)'>Remover</button>";
}

// funcao remove uma linha da tabela
function removeLinha(linha) {
var i=linha.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById('tbl').deleteRow(i);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Buttler</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <header class="main-container">
  <div>
   <a href="index.html"><img src="img/hotel.jpeg" alt="hotel"></a>

  </div>

  <aside class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">PEDIDOS EM ABERTO</a></li>
     <li><a href="pages/final.html">PEDIDOS FINALIZADOS</a></li>
    </ul>

  </aside>
 </header>

 <section class="header-title">

  <div class="main-title">
   <h3>Page aberta</h3>
  </div>

 </section>


 <section class="content">
  <button onclick="adicionaLinha('tbl')">Adicionar</button>
        <table id="tbl" class="tbl">
        <tr>
          <td>N° DO QUARTO</td>
          <td>PEDIDO</td>
          <td>STATUS</td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
 </section>




<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Buttler</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"> 
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <header class="main-container">
  <div>
   <a href="../index.html"><img src="../img/hotel.jpeg" alt="hotel"></a>

  </div>

  <aside class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../index.html">PEDIDOS EM ABERTO</a></li>
     <li><a href="final.html">PEDIDOS FINALIZADOS</a></li>
    </ul>

  </aside>
 </header>

 <section class="header-title">
  <div class="main-title">
   <h3>Page fechada</h3>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="content">
  <table id="tbl" class="tbl">
   <tr>
    <td>N° DO QUARTO</td>
    <td>PEDIDO</td>
    <td>STATUS</td>
   </tr>
   </table> 
 </section>



 <script src="../main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estas páginas estão sendo servidas por um servidor, ou é algo estático que você tem na sua máquina?

Answer (score -1):

Isso provavelmente não dá pra fazer só com javascript. O que você vai ter que fazer é criar um json contendo os dados da primeira página e adicionando um status no objeto que você clicou em remover, como por exemplo:

```js
{ "id" : "10", "quarto" : "5", "removido" : "true" }
```

Na outra página, você exibe só os objetos desse json cujo `removido` seja `true`

Comment: existem diversas outras formas de armazenar os dados no lado do cliente. Citei as mais utilizadas em minha resposta. Criar e armazenar em um arquivo JSON será bastante complexo para ele.

Answer (score -1):

Você possui **diversas possibilidades** de **passar as informações** **para a próxima página** **`.html`**. De acordo com suas tags inseridas na pergunta eu suponho que você não esteja utilizando nenhum **backend** e somente o **frontend** **"convencional (HTML5, CSS3 e JS)"** e **irei responder a sua pergunta baseada nisto**.

Antes de mais nada eu sugiro que você **leia alguns artigos citados abaixo**, os quais **são convenientes para sua pergunta**, **assim você pode passar para um próximo nível de conhecimento**.

> 1) [CLIENT SIDE](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lado_cliente)
>
> 2) [COMO O JAVASCRIPT FUNCIONA: O MECANISMO DE RENDERIZAÇÃO](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-the-rendering-engine-and-tips-to-optimize-its-performance-7b95553baeda)
>
> 3) [ARMAZENAMENTO NA WEB](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/?redirect_from_locale=pt)

Geralmente os **desenvolvedores inexperientes** precisam armazenar qualquer informação e imediatamente pensam em fazer algum tipo de upload para um servidor. Logo o **HTML5** mudou isto, **existem diversas tecnologias que permitem o armazenamento de dados do lado do cliente**. Os dados podem também ser **assíncronos ou síncronos** de volta para o **servidor ou permanecer sempre no cliente (Isto é decisão do desenvolvedor, ou seja, sua!).**

Lendo todo o conteúdo acima e sabendo disto, você pode escolher entre **muitas técnicas** para **armazenar dados do lado do cliente**, algumas delas são:

> 1) [WEB STORAGE](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)
>
> 2) [SQLITE](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)
>
> 3) [BANCO DE DADOS INDEXADOS (IndexedDB)](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb)

Pelo o que eu entendi com sua pergunta não muito detalhada e o seu modo de estruturação, code clean e boas práticas estou supondo que você está fazendo isto para aprendizagem, então eu sugiro que utilize o **WEB STORAGE** para tal.

**Siga as documentações e leia os artigos o qual eu encaminhei que você conseguirá fazer e irá subir de nível de conhecimento.**

**DICA:**

> Na **primeira página** onde você gera as informações, ao gerá-las salve no **WEB STORAGE** ***(Você pode escolher entre SessionStorage e LocalStorage, isto depende do que você realmente quer)***. Logo na **segunda página** onde você quer exibir as informações salvas, **você recupera os dados armazenados no WEB STORAGE**.